# Notification led not working when using NotificationCompat?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my notification, i want the led to blink in white color.
I am using NotificationCompat class from the support library to build the notification.

**Notification fires up nicely, but led doesn't blink. (tested on Nexus 4)**

Here's the code:

```
// Build notification
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify);
mBuilder.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.task_due));
mBuilder.setContentTitle(notify_title).setContentText(notify_descrip);
mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent());
mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
mBuilder.setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500);
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

// On notification tap
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SpecialActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

// Notify the user
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Is your screen off? The LED won't illuminate unless the screen is off.

Comment: Actually, LightFlow app was causing the problem. I disabled it and led is working fine now :)